# Save image from html to phone photo directory

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, web, web-applications

I have the below tag in my website for downloading image

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,%20iVBOdfd...." download="myimage.png" />
```

The above tag is working normally, when it is pressed, it will download the image without any issue.
When I tried this function on ios / android, the web browser will download the image to some "Download" folder instead of writing it to camera roll (IOS) / DCIM (android).

My question is, is it possible to write to camera roll or DCIM? If it is possible, how can I achieve it? This function is crucial to my application as my users always find it hard to navigate on phone to retrieve the downloaded images at later time.

P.S: My concern is more about the writing destination, filesystem access on phone, not the download itself.

P.S: this is a normal website written using html, vuejs. not native, not react native, not vue-native.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can't control the place where a other app downloads it file too. But if you make your own app you can simply download file and then write the file using a `outputStream` to any place on the phone: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible since it is the web browser who has access to the device and your web application cannot decide where to save the image. You'll need to implement an app to achieve the expected result. Also study Progressive Web Apps to see whether it's possible